# what does the proverb "A woman is only a woman, but a good cigar is a smoke" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, proverbs

I am studying English proverbs. One of them is:

> ***"A woman is only a woman, but a good cigar is a smoke"***.

I cannot understand the meaning of that. I searched internet but I could not find any satisfactory answer and there was no examples of using it. So what does that proverb mean? and I need some examples too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't a proverb - it's a line from a Rudyard Kipling poem '*The Betrothed*', so it has to be considered in context.

At face value, it would suggest that you can get some enjoyment out of a cigar - the act of smoking - but that you cannot get enjoyment out of a woman. That sentiment would seem misogynistic to most people.

If I understand [the poem](https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/poem/poems_betrothed.htm) correctly, it is written from the perspective of a man who is arguing with his fiancée about his smoking habit, and she is forcing him to choose between her or his habit. So the final line is an insult to her, that he has chosen to smoke in preference to his woman. The final lines of the poem suggest that his habit was formed before they were betrothed and that if she will not tolerate it then he cannot be with her.

Comment: @KateBunting - the engagement appears to be about to be broken off, too. It starts _Open the old cigar-box, get me a Cuba stout, For things are running crossways, and Maggie and I are out_ and ends _Light me another Cuba—I hold to my first-sworn vows. If Maggie will have no rival, I’ll have no Maggie for Spouse!_. For years I though Groucho Marx had originated the saying, rather than merely appropriating it.

Comment: It is possible that the cigar problem is merely one example of some incompatibility issues that have arisen; having realised this, he seeks solace in a good Cuba. British people of a certain age will recognise the notion expressed in the celebrated [Hamlet cigar advertisements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIckHmwZAeI)

Comment: I remember a couple of cheroots once got me through a time similar to that in the poem.

Comment: My father, who died ten years ago aged 93, attributed his longevity to his habit, over 50 years, of smoking a Corona cigar every Sunday evening.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That certainly flies in the face of decades of medical research and is quite irresponsible to say given the clear links to cancer. Some people may be genetically disposed to tolerate it, but the majority would not be so lucky. Does this comment really add to my answer?

Comment: @Astralbee - Comments about the solace to be found in tobacco would seem to be connected to the theme of the poem. Perhaps I should have added that I certainly do not recommend smoking at all, and (I suppose) it is possible that Father might have lived a bit longer if he had not smoked at all. I didn't mention the single malt. He smoked menthol cigarettes during the week.

Answer (score -3):

To that student, I say:

> You’re looking for knowledge where it’s not be found --
> There’s no hare to be chased by the loud baying hound --
> Nor will you grasp meaning when your mind’s in the throes
> Of great batches of drivel we should flush with a hose.
> Look at the words.  They tell you their tale,
> Speak loudly those meters, amusing as ale.
> Then you will get it and then you will laugh.
> Freed up from your dogma you never will gaffe.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question

Comment: I think it is meant to be fun...  But, dear user183783, please remember we are writing for non-native speakers of English, and writing in verse is more likely to confuse than to enlighten them. If you must write in verse please learn how to format it in markdown. And see [answer]